# android api resource qualifier - how to do ranges?

Tags: android, xml, android-resources

I need to set different menu options depending on the API level in android on the device.  Specifically, for API 10 - 15 i need a specific menu and for API 16 and beyond i need another menu. My applications minSdkVersion is api 10.

Right now the menu resource structure looks like this:

```
res/menu/menu.xml       (Default)
res/menu-v10/menu.xml    
res/menu-v11/menu.xml
res/menu-v12/menu.xml
res/menu-v13/menu.xml
res/menu-v14/menu.xml
res/menu-v15/menu.xml
```

do i really have to add a menu item for each level or can i make it in a range.

I wish i could do this:

```
res/menu/menu.xml       (Default)
res/menu-v10-v15/menu.xml
```

Is there a way to specify ranges in this way ? i do not see that in the [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#ApiLevels)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to specify ranges in this way ?

Not that way.

> do i really have to add a menu item for each level

You don't.

> Specifically, for API 10 - 15 i need a specific menu and for API 16 and beyond i need another menu

Then have two directories:

- `res/menu/menu.xml` for API Level 10-15
- `res/menu-v16/menu.xml` for API Level 16+

This assumes that your `minSdkVersion` is 10.